# Javascript and PHPMySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, printing

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbusername ='root';
$dbpassword ='';
$database ='mp19';

$link =mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','12345678');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mp19', $link);

if (!$link)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $link);}

$sql="(SELECT * FROM 3-33)";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $link);


if (!$result)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Date</th>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  var_dump($row);
  echo "<td>$row['date']</td></tr>";
  }
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

The connection is successful but the data doesn't get fetched from phpmysql and neither does it print in a table. Why is this so?

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: `while (mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query))` --- omg, what is this?!?!

Comment: She already asked question before and I pointed out error but she completely does not know how to fetch data from database through php. So i Edited her question to minimize errors

Comment: But when you edit the code, there's no usefull answer possible, because we are not commenting on the origional code?!

Comment: Not *at all* the original code. Doesn't even look like it anymore. :D

Comment: Can you clarify what data you're trying to retrieve?  `SELECT * FROM 3-33` is not a valid query and we'd like to be able to help you figure out what query you should be making in its place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a few errors. It seems you lack a basic understanding of how these functions work. Almost all of them return some variable (like a link resource or a row array) that you can use in the rest of your code. If a call fails, these functions return `false`. So you should check if the value if explicitly `false` (by using the `===` operator) and only continue if everything is ok. Then, you must use the result value of the function, not the function itself. mysql_query is merely the call, not the result.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbusername ='root';
$dbpassword ='';
$database ='mp19';

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','12345678');

if ($link === false)
{
    exit("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_select_db('mp19', $link) === false)
{
    exit("Could not select database mp19: " . mysql_error());
}

// Is '3-33' really your table name?! You should pick another name. 
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM 3-33)";

$resultset = mysql_query($sql, $link);

// (!$sql)? $sql SQL is always set here. It is just the string 
if ($resultset === false) 
{
    exit("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());
}

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Date</th>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
{
    $date = $row['fieldname'];
    echo "<td>$date</td></tr>";
}

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: "Almost all of them return an object" --- In this code there is no any object at all.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Picked the wrong words there. Fixed the text, but the point is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The query is invalid - try loading your mysql client at the command line and running it:

```
mysql -uroot mp19 -p
(SELECT * FROM 3-33)
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3-33' at line 1
```

Comment: You may want to explain WHY that query is invalid and provide a working solution, such as `SELECT * FROM `3-33``

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard for me to figure out from the original post what he meant to accomplish.  At first I thought he just wanted a query which would always return something, and thought SELECT * FROM 3-33 was equivalent to SELECT 3-33.  Now that you mention it, I suppose he could have a table named `3-33`... but, er, I'm not really sure why that would be the case either.  I'll leave a comment on the question itself suggesting he clarify what he's trying to do with the query.